# Basecamp OAuth2 with PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, basecamp

I am trying to create an app for Basecamp. I managed to connect and pull data using curl ([Basecamp API using cURL and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329476/basecamp-api-using-curl-and-php/15395769#15395769)). However this requires the users login data.

I would like to use OAuth2 with Basecamp as in https://github.com/37signals/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md. Unfortunately there is 0 documentation on this and I couldnt find any sample code. I saw there are several OAuth2 libraries http://oauth.net/code/, but I have no idea what to do with them.

Can somebody please show me some php sample code of how I would authenticate a user using OAuth2 in php and than make a request to the Basecamp API?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: did you find any resources ?

Answer (score -1):

I recently had to implement OAuth 2.0 for our company. I was also browsing the web to try and find information on the topic.  I came across these two websites, which helped alot.

[OAuth 2.0 Implementation Example](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/)

[Online Screencast](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/oauth)

Hope this helps.